# How to pass parameters to sqlps from a master windows powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a master powershell script as follows. It defines a single variable **$V1** and then launches the sqlps that uses this variable. Since sqlps is itself a minishell it does not recognise **$V1**

```
$V1 = "asdasd"    

sqlps -NoLogo -Command {
            invoke-sqlcmd -Query $V1 -ServerInstance "SomeImstamce" -Database "SomeDatabase" -Username "SomeUsernName" -Password "SomePassword"
      }
```

I therefore updated the sqlps -Command block to expect a parameter as follows. However I am not sure how to pass the outer $V1 variable value to the inner sqlps -Command Block

```
$V1 = "RBIQHSAPPD049v.b2b.regn.net"

sqlps -NoLogo -Command {
            param ($SqlPsParam)
            invoke-sqlcmd -Query $SqlPsParam  -ServerInstance "SomeImstamce" -Database "SomeDatabase" -Username "SomeUsernName" -Password "SomePassword"
      }
```

There is syntax help on  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280450.aspx and I have tried many combinations but it doesnot seem to work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

oh figure it out atlast

```
$V1 = "sdfsaf"
$V2 = "safd"

sqlps -NoLogo -Command {
            param ($SqlPsParam1, $SqlPsParam2)
            invoke-sqlcmd -Query $SqlPsParam  -ServerInstance "SomeImstamce" -Database "SomeDatabase" -Username "SomeUsernName" -Password "SomePassword"
      } -args $V1, $V2
```

Comment: Very helpful example - I had the same need to use parent script variables within sqlps.exe utility. Thank you :-).